# Wink API Subscriptions Stop Sending Overnight

Tags: iot, zigbee, z-wave, wink

I'm using the Wink API to control lights and thermostats etc. In the API you can subscribe to device topics to receive events such as when a light is turned on or off. This is handled through PubNub. I have this all working except that the events stop being sent if I leave the system overnight.

If I try to "manually" toggle a light by tapping the physical switch then normally an event is fired and received by my application via PubNub. Restarting my application and thus reconnecting to PubNub does NOT resolve the issue. The only way I've found to resolve the issue is to open the Wink app itself. Nothing else needs to be done but to open the Wink app. Then if I manually toggle the switch the event will show up and be received by my application. This solution works even if I don't restart my application.

There appears to be some sort of wake or keep-alive going on. Although I don't see anything in the Wink API docs that state such. There is also nothing sent from PubNub during this downtime. I have logging being sent out for the status(), message(), and presence() callbacks and nothing is logged from these overnight. Therefore taking all the above into account I believe the issue resides on the Wink side of things.

Unfortunately, Wink does not provide developer support. The Wink app is obviously doing something but because the transactions are encrypted it is unknown what it is doing. Also my test cycle is 8 hours long currently so it is difficult to debug this by trial and error. I'm working to see if this "timeout" is shorter than the overnight 8 hours I've experienced so far. i've also tried power cycling my Wink Hub yesterday but that did not resolve the issue.

Anyone else run into this issue? How do you keep subscriptions alive so that they are always sent?

Comment: I'm surprised to Wink has no developer support because I thought that is what it was designed for: developers. Anyway, they use PubNub and while we can't officially support what they implemented, it is possible that there might be some PubNub-y aspects that we can help you with. Please submit your details (code is nice and any logs) to [PubNub Support](https://support.pubnub.com) and mention this link so that we can refer back here with answers.

Comment: Thanks Craig. I posted a support ticket to PubNub. See if anything can be found.